# How to customize JSON format of error in validation in Lumen(Laravel)

Tags: php, json, laravel, lumen

I am sending error messages like this in case of errors in getting data from DB or any other issue:

```
return response()->json(['status' => 'Failed' ,'state'=>'100' , 'message'=>'You have not registered yet.' ], 401);
```

This gives me a JSON which has everything defined so I easily show the message whatever the problem is.

But in case of error in case of validation, I don't seem to have the power to change the format of the error response JSON.

```
   $this->validate($request, [
    'email' => 'required',
    'password' => 'required'
    ]);
```

I want to customize the error format as the one given above so that I don't have to change my error showing mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually create a validator and add your custom response if it fails, like this:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'email' => 'required',
    'password' => 'required'
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return response()->json(['status' => 'Failed' ,'state'=>'100' , 'message'=> $validator->errors()->first() ], 401);
}
```

Comment: Please add a source as I've gone through the doc but couldn't find a good solution

Comment: Just replace the `$this->validate(...)` call in your example with my code sample above and it should work!

Comment: I have it working but some blog or doc will be good option for my future help

Comment: Sure thing! Here is the section explaining manual validators in the official laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#manually-creating-validators