# How to return custom JSON array name and elements inside when validating in Lumen 7?

Tags: php, json, laravel, lumen

i am trying to return JSON of validation error messages in Lumen 7.2.1

At the moment Postman returns me this:

```
{
    "last_name": [
        "Pole zawiera niepoprawne znaki"
    ],
    "email": [
        "Email jest już zajęty"
    ]
}
```

I would like to return something like this:

```
{
    errors: [
        "last_name": [
            "Pole zawiera niepoprawne znaki"
        ],
        "email": [
            "Email jest już zajęty"
        ]
    ]
}
```

This is my update method in controller:

```
    /**
     * Update user
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param $id
     * @return JsonResponse
     * @throws ValidationException
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //validate incoming request
        $this->validate($request,
            [
                'name' => 'required|string|alpha',
                'last_name' => 'required|string|alpha',
                'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            ],
            [
                'name.required' => 'Pole Imię jest wymagane',
                'name.alpha' => 'Pole zawiera niepoprawne znaki',
                'last_name.required' => 'Pole Nazwisko jest wymagane',
                'last_name.alpha' => 'Pole zawiera niepoprawne znaki',
                'email.required' => 'Pole Email jest wymagane',
                'email.email' => 'Niepoprawny email',
                'email.unique' => 'Email jest już zajęty',
            ]);

        try {
            $user = User::findorFail($id);
            $user->update($request->all());
            return response()->json(['data' => $user], 200);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'User Update Failed!'], 409);
        }
    }
```

I have tried adding $errors = ['name.required'...,] but the result was the same.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46857342/how-to-customize-json-format-of-error-in-validation-in-lumenlaravel
Let me know if it works :)

Comment: Thanks but i will use approach listed below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all in line validation in controllers, is not at all an best approach, use `FormRequest` much cleaner and you get handling of errors for free. I once told lies to myself that the in line approach was quicker and no, it is not.

```
class UpdateUserRequest extends FormRequest {
    public function rules() {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|string|alpha',
            'last_name' => 'required|string|alpha',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            ];
    }

    public function messages() {
        return [
            'name.required' => 'Pole Imię jest wymagane',
            'name.alpha' => 'Pole zawiera niepoprawne znaki',
            'last_name.required' => 'Pole Nazwisko jest wymagane',
            'last_name.alpha' => 'Pole zawiera niepoprawne znaki',
            'email.required' => 'Pole Email jest wymagane',
            'email.email' => 'Niepoprawny email',
            'email.unique' => 'Email jest już zajęty',
         ];
    }
}
```

Transforming your validation exception should be done in `Exceptions/Handler.php`, this will make all exceptions transform properly, removing clunky logic from multiple controllers.

```
public function render($request, \Throwable $exception)
{
    if ($request->expectsJson() && $exception instanceof ValidationException) {
        return response()->json([
            'errors' => $exception->errors(),
        ], Response::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
    }

    ...
}
```

Check if API request or avoid this transformation with `$request->expectsJson()`, else simply transforming the result and we can make your controller method as simple as.

```
public function update(UpdateUserRequest $request, $id)
{
   $user = User::findorFail($id);

    $user->update($request->all());

    return response()->json(['data' => $user], 200);
}
```

And catching all exceptions does nothing, let the `Exceptions/Handler.php` handle that as well. For bonus points use model binding for the user too. But i think this is a big enough transformation as is.

Comment: Just realizing that this is a lumen question tagged with Laravel, you have to go through some hoops to make FormRequest work, should be possible or at worst, handle your request as you always did and throw new ValidationException or similar.

Comment: Made it working, thanks for help and a lot new information!